# Dynamics CRM Netzwerk

Tags: javascript, https, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

can anyone say me what is this Host : ***browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com*** and what does it matter in dynamics crm?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it used for telemetry tracking for various O365 applications. Unfortunately there is no official documentation stating its purpose, but some reading can be found here:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/spo-site-makes-a-call-to-browser-pipe-aria-microsoft-com/m-p/829128

and here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-we-disable-telemetry-and-tracking-in/9cc9db88-0047-4f3d-92c7-6fafbc933fd3?page=1